# Segmentation fault when importing libtorrent library on Android

Tags: android, python, c++, boost, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to run Libtorrent on an Android device, in Python for Android (https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android). I have the Libtorrent source files from RUTracker, an existing Android application that succesfully compiled the libtorrent library for Android. They are using JNI to communicate in Java with the Libtorrent library.

I also managed to compile their Libtorrent library, using the instructions on this website: https://github.com/pepibumur/Torrent-Movies. I first compiled Boost 1.49 with the NDK toolchain. After that I've compiled Libtorrent succesfully and I tested this .so file with a very simple Java application.

Now I want to compile with a Python wrapper so I can import the libtorrent library in Python. After some research, I found out that I have to create the following file and include it in the compilation process:

```
#include <boost/python/module.hpp>

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(libtorrent)
{
}
```

For this, I also need libpython so I compiled a .a file of the Python files I need and linked against it. When importing the module in Python, it gives a segmentation fault. Below, some of the most important lines of the stack trace are shown:

```
I/DEBUG   (  317):     #01  pc 0001c75c  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
I/DEBUG   (  317):     #02  pc 001ea5b3  /data/data/org.RUTorrent.example/files/lib/python2.7/site-packages/libtorrent.so (Py_FatalError+42)
I/DEBUG   (  317): 
I/DEBUG   (  317): stack:
I/DEBUG   (  317):          75231518  00000001  
I/DEBUG   (  317):          7523151c  6c12aaba  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-mark-stack (deleted)
I/DEBUG   (  317):          75231520  40110170  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   (  317):          75231524  724cf698  
I/DEBUG   (  317):          75231528  0000004e  
I/DEBUG   (  317):          7523152c  400e820d  /system/lib/libc.so (__sflush+56)
I/DEBUG   (  317):          75231530  40110220  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   (  317):          75231534  401134ac  
I/DEBUG   (  317):          75231538  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  317):          7523153c  400e922b  /system/lib/libc.so (_fwalk+34)
I/DEBUG   (  317):          75231540  400e84d5  /system/lib/libc.so (_cleanup)
I/DEBUG   (  317):          75231544  7523155c  [stack:6462]
I/DEBUG   (  317):          75231548  757d89d4  
I/DEBUG   (  317):          7523154c  00000002  
I/DEBUG   (  317):          75231550  df0027ad  
I/DEBUG   (  317):          75231554  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  317):     #00  75231558  7917c8bc  /data/data/org.RUTorrent.example/files/lib/python2.7/site-packages/libtorrent.so
I/DEBUG   (  317):          7523155c  fffffbdf  
I/DEBUG   (  317):          75231560  401101c4  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   (  317):          75231564  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  317):          75231568  401101c4  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   (  317):          7523156c  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  317):          75231570  40113da0  
I/DEBUG   (  317):          75231574  791a8af4  /data/data/org.RUTorrent.example/files/lib/python2.7/site-packages/libtorrent.so
I/DEBUG   (  317):          75231578  740c1ad0  /data/app-lib/org.RUTorrent.example-1/libpython2.7.so
I/DEBUG   (  317):          7523157c  400e4760  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_clone)
I/DEBUG   (  317):     #01  75231580  0000193e  
I/DEBUG   (  317):          75231584  78f3b5b7  /data/data/org.RUTorrent.example/files/lib/python2.7/site-packages/libtorrent.so (Py_FatalError+46)
I/DEBUG   (  317):     #02  75231588  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  317):          7523158c  7917bfb4  /data/data/org.RUTorrent.example/files/lib/python2.7/site-packages/libtorrent.so
I/DEBUG   (  317):          75231590  791a8af4  /data/data/org.RUTorrent.example/files/lib/python2.7/site-packages/libtorrent.so
I/DEBUG   (  317):          75231594  78f38b3b  /data/data/org.RUTorrent.example/files/lib/python2.7/site-packages/libtorrent.so (PyThreadState_Get+26)
I/DEBUG   (  317):          75231598  791a8af4  /data/data/org.RUTorrent.example/files/lib/python2.7/site-packages/libtorrent.so
I/DEBUG   (  317):          7523159c  78f35877  /data/data/org.RUTorrent.example/files/lib/python2.7/site-packages/libtorrent.so (Py_InitModule4+30)
I/DEBUG   (  317):          752315a0  000024f0  
I/DEBUG   (  317):          752315a4  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  317):          752315a8  5391ba4e  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
I/DEBUG   (  317):          752315ac  03d43237  
I/DEBUG   (  317):          752315b0  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  317):          752315b4  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  317):          752315b8  791a9014  /data/data/org.RUTorrent.example/files/lib/python2.7/site-packages/libtorrent.so
I/DEBUG   (  317):          752315bc  7909eeb7  /data/data/org.RUTorrent.example/files/lib/python2.7/site-packages/libtorrent.so
```

I'm not sure where this goes wrong. Is this an error in the internals of Boost.Python? Or is it an error in the Python library? Is there anything I can try to debug this error? It occurres when starting up the application since the import of libtorrent is the first line.